# Modifying a child theme

Tags: child-theme

I successfully created a copy of a theme in WordPress and now have a child version. I was hoping to be able to modify it further but from this point I do not understand what options are now given to me that were not given to me before.

For example, if I want to change the mobile-only menu from being located on the left in "House painter" to be centered, how would I go about and do that?

I am still a bit confused by CSS, script and so on. I was hoping to remove the current structure of the footer (currently divided in 5 equal parts) into a more simple structure but adding a png that would overlap the original content slightly. So was hoping to put a png in the center top -50 px for example.

Anyone could give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good resource with a lot of details about [Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).  I would suggest reading the entire thing.

You can override any file in your child theme by copying the parent theme's file and placing it in the same directory of your child theme.

For example, to make edits to your footer.php, the file you would most likely need to edit to remove some of the 5 columns you mentioned, you would copy the parent theme's footer.php and place it in the root of your child theme.  Then you can freely make changes to this file.

I would suggest doing the above and playing around with the layout to try to achieve what you want.  Then if you have more specific questions you can start a new question and get more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a Child Theme is so you can make changes to a theme without your changes being overwritten whenever the theme updates. With that in mind, now that you have a child theme you can copy over files from the parent theme and use them in the child theme.

For example, if your mobile menu is located in the parent themes `header.php` file - you can copy that file to your child theme and make any changes you see fit. WordPress will see that the child theme has a `header.php` and will use that file instead of the parent themes `header.php` file. The same can be done with the footer. Depending on the theme you may also be able to do this with functions and hooks.

In the future your parent theme may update but your child theme won't receive any automatic updates and your changes will be preserved. You can read more about Child Themes in the [WordPress Handbook - Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), specifically regarding [template overriding](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#adding-template-files).

---

If you're not sure how to fix something with CSS that kind of question may be better suited at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).